# Access time step in scipy solve_ivp()

Tags: python, scipy

I have a system of ODEs that I'm solving with scipy's solve_ivp() function. It works well but I'm having trouble accessing the time step used in each step. I know solve_ivp() passes the current time to the user defined function, but I need the time step used, not the current time. To solve this problem currently I'm setting the solve_ivp() min_step and max_step parameters as

```
min_step = max_step = my_time_step
```

so I know the time step. But surely there's a better way of doing this? I don't see any way in the solve_ivp() docs that would allow me to access the time step for a given step. Is the above solution the best way or have I missed a simpler solution?

**Additional information:**

I'm using solve_ivp() to calculate the evolution of a metal bead as it moves through air. The air composition, the bead radius, and the bead velocity all change with time. The metal bead is oxidized by the air with rate

```
rate=k[air] #rate has units of [mol m-3 s-1]
```

for rate constant k and air molarity [air], which has units mol m-3. The volume of air encountered per second is given by

```
vol_s = pi*radius**2*velocity #vol_s has units [m3 s-1]
```

Where radius is the radius of the bead (m), and velocity is the velocity of the bead (m s-1). In order to get the total air that reacts with the bead from rate I need to know the volume. The vol_s*time_step gives the volume, so rate * vol_s * time_step is the amount of product from the reaction per second. Thus the need to know the time_step.

Comment: You need the value of the time step in your gradient/Jacobian, or do you need it after the solver has finished? If the former, why? If latter, and you have `result = solve_ivp(...)`, then you can get the timesteps with `result.t`

Comment: I need the time step in the gradient. I added additional information to the question to explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I think that you should not need the timestep in the gradient, though. Notice that the velocity is in meters/second, and that you have the volume per second already. This gives `d(radius)/dt = k[air] * pi * radius **2 * velocity`. But notice we wrote `d(radius)/dt` -- this is exactly the derivative of radius with respect to time. So you already have the gradient. This is what you need for an ODE: a rate of change. An explicit *amount* of change would put you more in the realm of difference equations than ODEs.

Comment: Ah, that makes way more sense - can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Good luck :)