# accessing `solve_ivp` state on-the-fly

Tags: scipy

Is there a way to access the state of Scipy's `solve_ivp` during the integration? For instance, to access the timestep the solver has chosen, the errors, etc.? I'm asking for curiosity. A similar unanswered question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835006/access-time-step-in-scipy-solve-ivp).

Comment: What you can do is to create a termination event that stops the solver, for instance, whenever a step on the solution is obtained. Then the solver state can be accessed and you can decide to continue the integration or anything else. In the past I also tried to access the state of the solver on the fly through modification of the _ivp.py file, although personally I don't recommend this.

Comment: @Zarathustra It is a useful workaround if one needs to access the state only a few times throughout the simulation. Yet, for scenarios in which the state variable must be called repetitively (say at each timestep), I think this adds a huge overhead.

Comment: I am afraid then possible workarounds are quite restricted. The solve_ivp is thought to be more of a black-box approach to ODEs, where accesing the state of the solver explicitly is not directly possible. For such purposes you might be better off using the generic ODE interface https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html. I think that might fit better to your purposes in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not so well-documented option is to invoke the integrators directly.  See [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html) as an example.

Here is an example of how it could be used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

def fun(t, y):
    return -y
  
time_bound = 20.
# max_step used to make sure this actually takes multiple steps
max_step = 0.0001
y0 = [5]

rk45 = integrate.RK45(fun, 0, y0, time_bound, max_step=max_step)

# need to manually keep track of solution
t = []
y = []

while rk45.status == "running" and rk45.y[0] < 200:
    t.append(rk45.t)
    y.append(rk45.y)
    # do some additional stuff

    rk45.step()

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()
```

The amount of extra information is a bit limited however.  You can access the step size, but not error estimates.  I do not recommend modifying the solution outside the solver manually as most (all?) of the solvers do not accommodate those kind of changes.